# Ancestry rights to the UK through great-grandparents

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, residency, application-status, ancestry-visas

I would like to know if I can apply for ancestry to the UK with two of my great-grandparents being born there. Their daughter, my grandmother, was born in South Africa, but both her parents were born in the UK in the late 1800s. I can produce copies of both great-grandparents' birth certificates.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately for you, the [criteria for the UK ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa) are quite clear:

> ## Overview
>
> You can apply for a UK Ancestry visa if you:
>
> - are a Commonwealth citizen
> - are applying from outside the UK
> - are able to prove that one of your grandparents was born in the UK
> - are able and planning to work in the UK
> - meet the other eligibility requirements

Note the third bullet point.  You must be able to show that at least one *grandparent* was *born in the UK.*  That you have a grandparent born in South Africa whose parents were born in the UK will not help in this regard.